# Acer Aspire One screen resolution 1366x768

Tags: windows, installation, resolution, acer-aspire

I had XP running on my Acer Aspire One model AO75h1. Now with Windows 8, I'm not able to install Vista display driver - when I try, the "Operating sytem is not supported". The display runs at 1024x768 resolution, should be 1366x768, but windows 8 doesn't pick it up. How do I trick windows 8 into accepting a windows 7 driver (which works fine I'n told). Rollback is not an option.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Just go to this address:

```
http://www.acer.it/ac/en/US/content/drivers
```

Select your model in the list

and download drivers for Windows 7.

This is the direct link for the VGA adapter:

```
http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Driver/VGA/VGA_Intel_8.14.10.2003_W7x86_A.zip?acerid=633903111488906782&Step1=Netbook,%20Chromebook&Step2=Aspire%20One&Step3=AO751h&OS=702&LC=en&BC=Acer&SC=PA_6
```

I installed it without any problem on a similar netbook.

Once you downloaded this package, you can also avoid using the installer and look for drivers from "Device Manager"